# Найти координаты точки пересечения n отрезков

Tags: геометрия

Как найти координаты точки пересечения n отрезков, если известно, что все они пересекаются в одной точке?

Comment: Как заданы отрезки?

Comment: @VladD: А если эти два коллинеарны?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Вы случайно не с кафедры мат. анализа? Окей. Для случая, когда не все отрезки лежат на одной и той же прямой: Берём один отрезок. Перебирая остальные, находим другой, не лежащий на той же прямой. (Такой найдётся, иначе все лежали на одной прямой.) Пересечение этих двух отрезков непусто, т. к. пересечение всех непусто. Значит, пересечение этих отрезков есть пересечение содержащих их прямых и есть искомая точка.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi:  ...Второй случай, пускай все отрезки лежат на одной прямой. При помощи скалярного произведения легко найти координаты концов каждого из отрезков на этой прямой. Максимум из «левых» концов очевидно есть левый конец пересечения. По условию пересечение одноточечное, поэтому этот максимум и соответствует пересечению.

Answer (score 1):

Найдите точку пересечения двух, очевидно же. Остальные проходят через ту же точку по условию. Достаточно даже найти точку пересечения двух прямых, содержащих первый и второй отрезок, т. к. прямые пересекаются в той же точке.

Comment: Комментарий Влада откатил, т.к. в условии ясно указано, что это отрезки, и что они все пересекаются. То есть никаких коллинеарностей или двух отрезков на одной прямой тут нет.